# How to add picture into JButton using JFilechooser

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jfilechooser

`JFileChooser` won't work I got an error on line:

`btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file)));`

Please help me , I'm a beginner.  It gives me this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
>       at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
>       at RecordManagementSystem.addRecord$1.actionPerformed(addRecord.java:185)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

**Code:**

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            int result = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {              
                try {
                    btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file)));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: May I recommend that you revise your error catching strategy instead of just throwing the error into a `JOptionPane`, consider logging the error in a way that you can review it. In my apps, I want to know about 110% of the errors that are thrown.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the file from the JFileChooser **before** it has been selected, and so `fc.getSelectedFile()` will return `null`.

Solution: get the File in the if block **after** the JFileChooser has been displayed.

```
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {              
    try {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();  // **** line added ****
        btnNewButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(file)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

---

as an aside, I like to avoid over-compression of my code to ease my finding errors if any occur. So instead I'd do something like so:

```
if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {              
    try {
        File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
        Image image = ImageIO.read(file);
        Icon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        btnNewButton.setIcon(icon);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // log error
    }
}
```